# How can I be sure that Ubuntu runs decently on Dell Inspiron 660 with the following specifics?

Tags: nvidia, dell, inspiron

I intend to buy a new dell inspiron 660 with the specifics below and I want to switch simultaneously to Ubuntu. Can I expect that Ubuntu will run decently on this system or will I encounter problems? Would you recommend another system instead?

Dell Inspiton 660:
Intel Core i5-3330 (6M Cache, up to 3.2 GHz)
8 GB DDR3 SDRAM at 1600 MHz
2 TB-Serial ATA drive (7,200 UPM)
NVIDIA GeForce GT 620 1 GB
DVD+/-RW Drive
Dell Wireless DW1506

Regards 
Clemens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well without the graphics card (and other slight modifications) it is [certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201201-10370/) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS